# Changing sign of numbers +/- multiple files

Tags: sed

I want to reverse the sign of numbers in column x (2) in multiple files. For example:

From

> 1  | 2.0
>
> 2   |  -3.0
>
> 3   | 1.0

To

> 1    |-2.0
>
> 2    |3.0
>
> 3    |-1.0

I am using `sed '/^-/ {s/.//;b};s/^/-/'` file command, but it does not work. Any suggestion?

Comment: the command you provided works for me on GNU sed, what is the output you get? and what is your sed version?

Comment: My output does not change. I want to change the column 5 of my file, so where should I indicate that

Comment: and even then, your output should change..

Comment: How can I find out which sed version I am using?

Comment: try `sed --version` ... also, you really need to change sample input file to reflect multiple columns and relevant expected output... saying `column x` is easy to miss

Comment: My sed version is : sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more "proper" way using actual math is easy with `awk`.   For example if you want to negate columns 2 and 3:

```
awk '{print $1, -$2, -$3}'
```

Comment: I use awk '{print $1, -$2, -$3}' old_file>new_file, and it worked. However, I cannot  apply to the multiple files.

Comment: I mean how should I loop in awk

Comment: @user3527941: You loop in the shell, not awk.  Write a "while" or "for" loop in bash for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat ip.txt 
1 | 2.0
2 | -3.0
3 | 1.0
```

Modifying `sed` command from OP, not suited to easily modify for a different column or different delimiter

```
$ sed -E '/^(.*\|\s*)-[0-9]/ {s/^(.*\|\s*)-/\1/;b}; s/^(.*\|\s*)/&-/' ip.txt 
1 | -2.0
2 | 3.0
3 | -1.0
```

With `perl` where it is easier to specify delimiter and modify specific column

```
$ perl -F'\|' -lane '$F[1] =~ m/-/ ? $F[1] =~ s/-// : $F[1] =~ s/\d/-$&/; print join "|", @F' ip.txt 
1 | -2.0
2 | 3.0
3 | -1.0
```

To modify multiple files inplace within a folder, use the `-i` option

```
sed -i -E '/^(.*\|\s*)-[0-9]/ {s/^(.*\|\s*)-/\1/;b}; s/^(.*\|\s*)/&-/' *
```

and

```
perl -i -F'\|' -lane '$F[1] =~ m/-/ ? $F[1] =~ s/-// : $F[1] =~ s/\d/-$&/; print join "|", @F' *
```

If number format is not an issue,

```
$ perl -F'\|' -lane '$F[1] = -$F[1]; print join "|", @F' ip.txt 
1 |-2
2 |3
3 |-1
```